# Blend clipped image in Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, blending

Looking to try and fade out an image in illustrator using the blend tool.

At first, I tried blending 2 clipping groups, but I knew that wasn't going to work.

Then I tried blending just the linked image, but that wasn't working either.

Is there anyway to blend a clipping mask so that an image can fade out on the edges?

Comment: I feel like this question was just answered on here...let me look.

Comment: @JohnManly I'm sure how to use an opacity mask is, but I wasn't sure of how I should do it for an image that I wanted clipped. Different way of asking the same question - I just didn't know the other way to ask the question or what to search for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know of this is not what you're talking about

Place your image.

[image: base image]

Make the shape that will be the clipping mask over the image you want to be clipped. I added a gradient to the circle and made the black end 0% opacity.

[image: clipping mask]

Select both objects. Go to transparency options and select "create mask" and clip. Your options might be different depending on how you have your document setup.

[image: Clipping mask options]

Result

[image]